# Socket.io - Can someone impersonate another socket id?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

In a socket.io room, some socket ids have more privileges than other socket ids. I store the socket ids who have more privileges, and I check if you have permission to execute an action ensuring your socket id is among those I stored. My doubt is: since everyone knows all the other socket ids in the room, can someone impersonate another socket id to obtain more privileges?

Answer (score 0):

There no short answer as it’s dependent upon you own design and implementation. However, there isn’t an inherent risk it’s dependent on how your using the ids.

Please review [Socket.io - Is the "socket ID" considered sensitive information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568559/socket-io-is-the-socket-id-considered-sensitive-information)

If you found this useful please mark as answer. Thanks

Comment: My question is just if I can impersonate another socket id, and I didn't find a clear answer ...

Comment: If your using the ids to distinguish users or set rules / permissions and it’s viewable or accessible  then yes. The safest bet would be to just use a web token to encrypt / decrypt your ids server side

Comment: It looks like it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600057/should-the-socket-io-socket-id-be-secret

Comment: Can you please provide a PoC in which you pretend to be another socket io?

Comment: I mean, another socket id.

Comment: Dude it’s not inherently a security risk but if you expose your socket ids and reveal how they are being used to distinguish roles or at the very least show who has what role, are we really debating if this would be an issue ? So, analyze your implementation and either redesign or tokenize your socket ids, and decode when you need them.

Comment: Please let me formulate the question in another way. In a room there are two socket ids (let's call them 'a' and 'b'), and they both know their socket ids. Can 'b' pretend to be 'a'? So can 'b' change his socket id? If yes, can you please provide a PoC?

Comment: Not sure how to respond but, I found this article that discusses intercepting websockets and socket io - modifying rules etc. https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/how-to-hack-websockets-and-socket-io/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily avoid this with JWT, so you can trust the id in the payload always.
The JSON Web Token can have any Object like `{id: 'random-id', privilege: 'admin}` which can be validated in your backend with your secret. 
See [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) or [socketio-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-jwt-auth) for NodeJs.
Hope this can help.

Comment: So is it possible to impersonate another socket id?